# Poor display of p:textEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 6.1 and I am trying out the primefaces text editor component. I am using the text editor's sample code on [primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml).

Here is the code of the **index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>    
        <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
        <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="#{editorView.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor1').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

        <h3 class="first">Custom Toolbar</h3>
        <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor2" value="#{editorView.text2}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Enter your content">
            <f:facet name="toolbar">
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                    <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                    <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                </span>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <select class="ql-font"></select>
                    <select class="ql-size"></select>
                </span>
            </f:facet>
        </p:textEditor>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor2').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

        <p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:outputPanel id="display">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
                <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text}" escape="false" />

                <h3>Custom</h3>
                <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text2}" escape="false" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>     
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**The code of the controller is that of the [showcase](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml#j_idt101:j_idt104), but in a default package.**

Here is a screen shot of interface after running the code.

[image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Works for me... [mcve] please

Comment: Can you please update your question with some code ?!

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi: 'some code' is dangerous. What OP thinks is some 'relevant' code, might effectively not be relevant. An [ mcve ] (without the spaces) becomes [mcve] and is explicit in multiple ways

Comment: @Kukeltje I just want to verify that he didn't modify the example code of Primefaces. Anyway, you're right !

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: So if you remove `<h3 class="first">Custom Toolbar</h3>` it all works? Or if you remove the dialog? If not, it it is not a [mcve]... And did you look at the browser console? Any errors? My bet is there is a javascript error or are you using an older PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje removing that doesn't resolve the problem. I just checked the console and I am having 8 errors. I have updated my question.

Comment: I know it does not solve the problem, it makes your code in the Q more a [mcve]. You can remove lots more... Always better to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Cool, now you see all sorts of javascript errors. Including ones from the textEditor, commandButton and most likely if you look at the network tab you have some 404's or other errors? Looking at the first line, it seems JQuery is not automatically loaded. Any indication jquery is in the source html? And most likely the commandButtons are not working either... So the bad display is a result of something completely else... That part should be investigated. Next time please do all these steps first... it is called 'debugging' (root-cause-analysis)

Comment: Hmmm otoh, at the end there is a jquery.js reference... Strange, sure this all code that is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working very fine. However, just for showing it displays fine, I simplified it in such a way you can avoid using a `ManagedBean`. In the real world you do need it:

```
 <h:form>    
        <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
        <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="TEXT1" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor1').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

        <h3 class="first">Custom Toolbar</h3>
        <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor2" value="TEXT2" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Enter your content">
            <f:facet name="toolbar">
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                    <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                    <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                </span>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <select class="ql-font"></select>
                    <select class="ql-size"></select>
                </span>
            </f:facet>
        </p:textEditor>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor2').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

        <p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:outputPanel id="display">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
                <h:outputText value="TEXT3" escape="false" />

                <h3>Custom</h3>
                <h:outputText value="TEXT4" escape="false" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>     
    </h:form>
```

I recommend you to:

1. Check if your **Primefaces** is really upgraded to the 6.1 version & that you're not using two versions of **Primefaces** at the same time
2. Clear your Web-Browser cache (Or change your WebBrowser)
3. Clear your project & rebuild it(with Dependencies if you're using **Maven**)

[image: Screen Shot of the runing interface]

Comment: _"However, I simplified it in such a way you can avoid using a ManagedBean"_ Why? Just for demonstrating it works?

Comment: @Kukeltje to minimize the using of several files & avoid confusion !

Comment: I noticed so @MehdiBouzidi, it was a jQuery issue. I am using the Ultima template in my project, and there I didn't have this issue.

Comment: @cdaiga glad it helps